# Extract strings from same member into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table data:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    member_id VARCHAR(3)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    member_id VARCHAR(3),
    index_1 INT,
    memo VARCHAR(300)
);

INSERT INTO A (member_id)
VALUES 
('ABC'),
('BNM'),
('TCC'),
('GHJ'),
('WER')  ;

INSERT INTO B (member_id, index_1, memo)
VALUES 
('ABC', 1, 'she has @sys google'),
('ABC', 2, 'she wants apple'),
('BNM', 3, 'He has @sys yahoo'),
('BNM', 4, 'He is 9'),
('BNM', 5, 'He went out'),
('TCC', 3, 'He loves chocolate'),
('TCC', 7, 'He sell bags'),
('GHJ', 2, 'No info'),
('WER', 2, 'she has @sys google') ;
```

Code:

```
select A.member_id, B.index_1, B.memo
from A
Left join B
on A.member_id=B.member_id
Order By B
```

original table looks like this:

```
member_id   index_1  memo
ABC         1        she has @sys google
ABC         2        she wants apple
BNM         3        He has @sys yahoo
BNM         4        He is 9
BNM         5        He went out
TCC         3        He loves chocolate
TCC         7        He sell bags
GHJ         2        No info
WER         2        she has @sys google
```

Now I want to alter the code to change the table format. I want to keep every member's first memo with @sys and last memo without @sys in one row. Every member will only have one row of data in this case.

Code:

```
select A.member_id, 
case when memo like '%@sys% and memo like '%google%' then 'google'
     when memo like '%@sys% and memo like '%yahoo%' then 'yahoo'
     else 'other'
End as memo,
case when memo not like '%@sys% and max(index_1) then memo  
    else ''
End as memo_2  --not sure how to do memo_2
from A
Left join B
on A.member_id=B.member_id
Order By B
```

expected result like this:

```
member_id   memo                    memo_2
ABC         google                  she wants apple
BNM         yahoo                   He went out
TCC         other                   He sell bags
GHJ         other                   No info
WER         google
```

Comment: It would help to also show the input data of the two tables rather than the outcome of a query only.

Comment: i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: LEFT JOIN twice? Or GROUP BY.

Comment: @jarlh the table is very big

Comment: That's why _you_ are expected to create a _minimal_ data set.

Comment: The provided table B does not have member_id column.

Comment: @Biak I just updated

Comment: @Lara19 `CREATE TABLE B (
    index_1 INT,
    memo VARCHAR(300)
);` still missing..

Comment: could you try with this? https://dbfiddle.uk/Wp6mMpAi

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understand you right. Here is my try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.member_id,
  case when b_sys.memo like '%google%' then 'google'
       when b_sys.memo like '%yahoo%' then 'yahoo'
       else 'other'
  end as memo,
  isnull(b_2.memo, '') memo_2
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN (
    select member_id, memo,
        rank() over(partition by member_id order by index_1) rn
      from B
      where memo like '%@sys%'
  ) b_sys ON b_sys.member_id = A.member_id and b_sys.rn = 1
  LEFT JOIN (
    select member_id, memo,
        rank() over(partition by member_id order by index_1 DESC) rn
      from B
      where memo NOT like '%@sys%'
  ) b_2 ON b_2.member_id = A.member_id and b_2.rn = 1
  ORDER BY 1
```

In first join we pick the first record ordered by index_1, in second - ordered by index_1 but in descending order.

You can try it here - https://dbfiddle.uk/lRIBqtq2

Comment: A more reader friendly version of this [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xov9Vbh3)

Answer (score 1):

See example

```
select member_id,sysName memo,memo2
from(
  select a.member_id,b.index_1 index_1,b.memo memo,b2.index_1 index_12,b2.memo memo2
    ,case when b.memo like '%@sys%' and b.memo like '%google%' then 'google'
         when b.memo like '%@sys%' and b.memo like '%yahoo%' then 'yahoo'
     else 'other'
     end sysName
    ,row_number()over(partition by a.member_id order by b.index_1,b2.index_1 desc)rn
  from a
  left join b on b.member_id=a.member_id 
    and (b.memo like '%@sys%' and (b.memo like '%google%' or b.memo like '%yahoo%'))
  left join b b2 on b2.member_id=a.member_id 
      and (b2.memo not like '%@sys%')
)y 
where rn=1
```

Output

| member_id | memo | memo2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | google | she wants apple |
| BNM | yahoo | He went out |
| GHJ | other | No info |
| TCC | other | He sell bags |
| WER | google | null |
| XY1 | google | he like lemon |

with test data

```
INSERT INTO A (member_id)
VALUES 
('ABC'),
('BNM'),
('TCC'),
('GHJ'),
('WER'),
-- added
('XY1')
;

INSERT INTO B (member_id, index_1, memo)
VALUES 
('ABC', 1, 'she has @sys google'),
('ABC', 2, 'she wants apple'),
('BNM', 3, 'He has @sys yahoo'),
('BNM', 4, 'He is 9'),
('BNM', 5, 'He went out'),
('TCC', 3, 'He loves chocolate'),
('TCC', 7, 'He sell bags'),
('GHJ', 2, 'No info'),
('WER', 2, 'she has @sys google'),
-- added
('XY1', 1, 'he has @sys google'),
('XY1', 2, 'he has @sys google'),
('XY1', 3, 'he like banana'),
('XY1', 4, 'he has @sys bing'),
('XY1', 5, 'he like lemon')
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qYjaSZ0u)

Answer (score 1):

```
I tried with "with Clause" but poor in alias name, hope that is understandable. this may works for you.



with crk as 

(select A.member_id as a_mid, B.*,
case 
 when memo like '%@sys%' and memo like '%google%' then 'google'
 when memo like '%@sys%' and memo like '%yahoo%' then 'yahoo' else '' end output,
 max(index_1) over ( partition by A.member_id order by B.member_id) mx,
case
 when memo like '%@sys%' and (memo like '%google%' or  memo like '%yahoo%') then '' 
else 'other' end rst 
from A  join B on A.member_id = B.member_id),

crk1 as

(select *,
         max(output) over (partition by A_mid order by index_1) mxx,
         case when mx = index_1 and rst <>'' then memo else '' end 
         memo_1 from crk)
select a_mid as member_id, case when mxx='' then rst else mxx end memo,
                 memo_1 from crk1 where index_1=mx
```

[Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cy3tFLC2)

Comment: I think, condition check ``when memo like '%@sys%' and memo like '%google%' or  memo like '%yahoo%'`` is equal ``when (memo like '%@sys%' and memo like '%google%') or  memo like '%yahoo%'``. See (https://dbfiddle.uk/JdvjtmSo).

Comment: @ValNik Yes both are same & giving the same result.

Comment: Should be ``when memo like '%@sys%' and (memo like '%google%' or  memo like '%yahoo%')``

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct a member_id,
    first_value(b.memo) over (partition by a.member_id order by case when b.memo like '@sys' then 0 else 1 end, b.index_1) as memo1,
    first_value(b.memo) over (partition by b.member_id order by case when b.memo like '@sys' then 1 else 0 end, b.index_1 desc) as memo2
from A a left outer join B on b.member_id = a.member_id
```